# Changing Unicode character to string

Tags: vb.net, unicode

I have to following string:

```
Dim text As String = "user̲upload"
```

I want to change the Unicode character @0332 to underscore. I have the following code for this:

```
Dim test As New Text.StringBuilder
test.Append(text.Replace("@0332", "_"))
Dim normalizedUrl As String = test.ToString()
```

However it does not work, my "test" string has the same value as "text" variable. Anyone has an idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can;

`text.Replace(ChrW(&H332), "_")`